# possible to use sequelize without a database connection

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

We would like to use sequelize to do validations on a set of objects (firstName length, email, boolean etc...). We will be proxying these to call a microservice which will then store them (not responsible for this architecture btw).

Is this possible? A dev tried it but got the message “No database selected”.

Comment: In that case, why not mock it (sequelize) ?

Comment: thanks - that's one possibility. It looks like it's not as simple as just filling in the options pieces as I think it will try to authenticate. So I'm hesitant to go down that path as there might be unanticipated issues. Similar to that, we could monkey patch its isAuthenticated method to always return true. We could be meaning different ideas of mocking though - I do mostly Rails with mocking usually referring to testing.